# Three.js FirstPersonControl does nothing

Tags: three.js

I implemented the following short script:

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

var camera;
var controls;
var scene;
var renderer;
var container;

var controls;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var light;
var floor;
var movingGeometry;

function setup() 
{
    var viewAngle = 45;
    var aspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;
    var near = 0.1;
    var far = 20000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewAngle, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  

    scene.add(camera);

    controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
    controls.movementSpeed = 70;
    controls.lookSpeed = 0.05;
    controls.noFly = true;
    controls.lookVertical = false;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);

    container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    createLight();
    createFloor();
    createSkyBox();
    createGeometry();

    animate();
}

function createLight()
{
    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,0);

    scene.add(light);
}

function createFloor()
{
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00FF00});

    floor = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 3, 1, 1, 1), floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

    scene.add(floor);   
}

function createSkyBox()
{
    var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000);
    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000FF, side: THREE.BackSide});
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial);

    scene.add(skyBox);
}

function createGeometry()
{
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);

    movingGeometry = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    movingGeometry.position.set(0, 28, 0);

    scene.add(movingGeometry);  
}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();       
    update();
}

function render() 
{
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    controls.update();
}

function update()
{
    var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
    var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
    var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second

    if (keyboard.pressed("W"))
    {
        movingGeometry.translateZ(-moveDistance);
    }

    if (keyboard.pressed("S"))
    {
        movingGeometry.translateZ(moveDistance);
    }

    if (keyboard.pressed("A"))
    {
        movingGeometry.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
    }

    if (keyboard.pressed("D"))
    {
        movingGeometry.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
    }

    var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,200);
    var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(movingGeometry.matrixWorld);

    camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
    camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
    camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
    camera.lookAt(movingGeometry.position);
}
```

I wanted to implement a camera which is sticking to an object. If i use 'w', 'a', 's', 'd' i can move the object and the camera follows. But i also want to be able to rotate the camera (at its position) by leftclick + dragging and i also want to rotate the object by rightclick + dragging (the typical first person behaviour).

So i added the FirstPersonControls from Three.js to the camera. The result: nothing happens when i use the mouse or click or anything and i also have no idea what i need to do to rotate the object by rightclicking and dragging.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight it seems like you have a problem with overwriting the cameras `lookAt` 
Since in `update()` you do :
    `camera.lookAt(movingGeometry.position);` 
List item
Your order of execution order is:

- animate

  - (your) render
  - (threejs) render
  - (threejs) controls update
- (your) update

and in your update you overwrite the cameras lookat from the first person controls.